# KendoUI - Treeview: How to prevent the item drag n drop from one node to another?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, dojo, treeview, kendo-treeview

I'm working on drag and drop the node item with in the same node. It is working as expected. But it allows to drag and drop the child item from one node to another. It should be prevented.

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OKAYo/4)

[Screenshot](http://i.giphy.com/3o6ZtiQ7LULNTeSKOs.gif)

In the attached screenshot. The last step should not happen. i.e. moving the **SubItem** to the **Item** level.

Appreciate your support to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent that with some custom logic in the `drop` event.

```
drop: function(e) {
    // Apply your own logic here
    e.setValid(false);
}
```

You just need to validate beforehand whether the element can be droppen here, and if not call the `setValid` method.

Additional information can be found on the [KendoUI docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#events-drop).

Comment: Thank you Philipp for the response. 

Is there is any way to get the selected item node? so I can validate against other node.

Comment: Yes, the `drop-event` does expose a `sourceNode`, and even a `destinationNode`  property if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/angular">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="box-col">
            <h4>TreeView</h4>
            <div kendo-tree-view="tree"
             k-data-source="treeData"
             drag-and-drop="true"
             k-drag="onDrag"
             k-on-change="selectedItem = dataItem"
                 k-on-drop="onDrop(kendoEvent)">
                <span k-template>
                     {{dataItem.text}} <button class='k-button' ng-click='click(dataItem)'>Select</button>
                 </span>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-col" ng-show="selectedItem">
          <h4>Selected: {{selectedItem.text}}</h4>
          <button class="k-button" ng-click="addAfter(selectedItem)">Add item below</button>
          <button class="k-button" ng-click="addBelow(selectedItem)">Add child item</button>
          <button class="k-button" ng-click="remove(selectedItem)">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .k-treeview .k-in {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
      .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
          $scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({ data: [
            { id:1, text: "Item 1" },
            { id:2, text: "Item 2", items: [
              { id:1, text: "SubItem 2.1" },
              { id:2, text: "SubItem 2.2" }
            ] },
            { id:3, text: "Item 3" }
          ]});

          $scope.click = function(dataItem) {

            alert(dataItem.text);
          };

          function makeItem() {
            var txt = kendo.toString(new Date(), "HH:mm:ss");
            return { text: txt };
          };

          $scope.addAfter = function(item) {
            var array = item.parent();
            var index = array.indexOf(item);
            var newItem = makeItem();
            array.splice(index + 1, 0, newItem);
          };

          $scope.addBelow = function() {
            // can't get this to work by just modifying the data source
            // therefore we're using tree.append instead.
            var newItem = makeItem();
            $scope.tree.append(newItem, $scope.tree.select());
          };

          $scope.remove = function(item) {
            var array = item.parent();
            var index = array.indexOf(item);
            array.splice(index, 1);

            $scope.selectedItem = undefined;
          };

                $scope.onDrag = function(e) {
            console.log("e.statusClass : " + e.statusClass);

             if (e.statusClass.indexOf("add") >= 0) {
                // deny the operation
                e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
             }
          }
          $scope.onDrop = function(e) {
             if($scope.tree.parent(e.sourceNode).data('uid') != $scope.tree.parent(e.destinationNode).data('uid'))
             {
              e.preventDefault();
             }
          }
    })
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: It is working fine on onDrop. Is't possible to get the `e.destinatonNode` in `onDrag` function. Bze, the icon is misleading. It says, it will allow to drop, but it is not. check the [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VlPG1.png).

Is there any way to tackle this.

Comment: I will try and let you know.